# jQuery and google maps auto complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have Google Maps Autocomplete working on several`input` tags like this:

```
 <input class="controls pac-input" id="pac-input" type="text" onfocus="geolocate()" placeholder="Type custom address" />
```

To enable Google Maps auto-complete, I have the following code:

```
//https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
$(document).ready(function () {

    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('pac-input')), { types: ['geocode'] });

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        MyFunc();
    });

});
```

And then, in the `MyFunc()` function I do what I need:

```
function MyFunc() {
    var fullAddress = autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address;
    var input = $(this);
    //stuff that uses input
}
```

This code however, has two problems:

- The first is that i am using an Id, to affect multiple input boxes (I have many input fields). I tried selecting by class but it fails with error ´undefined´. How can I apply that function to a collection of input fields?
- How do I know which field is being clicked? I tried using the jquery `$(this)` but it aint working. How can jQuery help me ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your `MyFunc()` function and the inputs please.

Comment: @RhapX: done ! I updated the post as requested!

Comment: Why do you have multiple inputs? What's the point?

Comment: @MrUpsidown: I have a table with multiple addresses and I wand the user to be able to specify them. Thus, each entry has an input field for the user to type an address.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't *need* jQuery for this. Here is a working example using only javascript:

HTML:

```
<input class="autocomplete" id="ac1" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>
<input class="autocomplete" id="ac2" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>
<input class="autocomplete" id="ac3" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>
```

JavaScript:

```
var acInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete");

for (var i = 0; i < acInputs.length; i++) {

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(acInputs[i]);
    autocomplete.inputId = acInputs[i].id;

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        console.log('You used input with id ' + this.inputId);
    });
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/42usv81j/)</kbd>

If you want to do it with jQuery then you can try this way:

```
$('.autocomplete').each(function() {
    
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($(this)[0]);
    autocomplete.inputId = $(this).attr('id');

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        console.log('You used input with id ' + this.inputId);
    });
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/ca53pzzm/)</kbd>

Hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed it helped ! Bounty awarded !

Comment: `autocomplete.inputId = $(this).attr('id');` was searching for how to reach the input. Couldn't remember what I've used for markers a million times.. Smart!

Answer (score -1):

In order to find out which input element is being called, you could pass the event to `MyFunc()`. Using `$(this)` isn't going to check outside of that function to see what called it.

Update the `addListener` to the following.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function (e) {
    MyFunc(e);
});`
```

And update `MyFunc()` to

```
function MyFunc(e) {
    var fullAddress = autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address;
    var input = e;
    //stuff that uses input
}
```

You can then use `input` as the variable that holds the information about the element being updated. If you do `console.log(input);` below the `var input = e;` you will see a list of items you can use to get the data.

You may be most interested in setting `var input = e;` to `var input = e.target;` instead. This will allow you to get the information about the input easily.

Example: `input.value` would return the value of the input in question.

Comment: I get an `undefined` error when I try your solution :S Is there any other way?